# C# variable changes value unexpectedly

Tags: c#

The title basically says it all. The variable "answer" in my code randomly changes value to another random number when it is defined.
The program is supposed to ask ten random maths questions and tell the user if they have got the correct answer or not, however this doesn't seem to be working at all.
Once the variable has changed, the program then also asks about 3 more questions, and tells the user the answer to each is incorrect.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random R = new Random();
        double solution = 0;
        string sign = "";

        int score = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int X = R.Next(1, 5);
            int Y = R.Next(1,10);
            int Z = R.Next(1,10);

            switch (X)
            {
                case 1:
                    solution = Y + Z;
                    sign = "+";
                    break;
                case 2:                       
                    solution = Y - Z;
                    sign = "-";
                    break;
                case 3:                        
                    solution = Y / Z;
                    sign = "/";
                    break;
                case 4:                        
                    solution = Y * Z;
                    sign = "X";
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("What is " + Y + " " + sign + " " + Z + "?");
             double answer = Console.Read();
            if (answer == solution)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");
                score = score + 1;
                Console.Read();
            }
            else if (answer != solution)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. The correct answer is " + solution);
                Console.Read();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your program with a debugger?

Comment: set breakpoints and debug through your code to see what is happening.

Comment: also, your if / else if / else at the bottom doesn't make sense. Under what circumstances do you imagine the code in the else block would be executed?

Comment: Also: Are you SURE that you want to get the answer this way? From what I read  Console.Read() gives you the ascii code of the next character (thus an int). And you want to get a double number which usually consists of more than only 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `Console.Read()`. This will return the characters number. Starting at 48 (0x30) for character `0`. That's why all of your answers are incorrect.

So I suggest you use `Console.ReadLine()` and then parse the string to `answer`.

```
        double answer;
        if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            continue;
        }

        if (answer == solution)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct");
            score = score + 1;
        }
        else if (answer != solution)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. The correct answer is " + solution);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `Console.Read()` which returns only the next character code. Instead, you should use `Console.ReadLine()`. Also after you check the answers you use some unnecessary `Console.Read()`(s). I have removed them and this code is working perfectly fine: -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Random R = new Random();
    double solution = 0;
    string sign = "";

    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int X = R.Next(1, 5);
        int Y = R.Next(1,10);
        int Z = R.Next(1,10);

        switch (X)
        {
            case 1:
                solution = Y + Z;
                sign = "+";
                break;
            case 2:                       
                solution = Y - Z;
                sign = "-";
                break;
            case 3:                        
                solution = Y / Z;
                sign = "/";
                break;
            case 4:                        
                solution = Y * Z;
                sign = "X";
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("What is " + Y + " " + sign + " " + Z + "?");
        double answer = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (answer == solution)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct");
            score = score + 1;
        }
        else if (answer != solution)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. The correct answer is " + solution);
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing is that the division questions are actually integer divisions. If you want decimals instead, you should use something like `solution = Math.Round((double)((decimal)Y / (decimal)Z), 3);` to check a value rounded to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that Console.Read returns an integer code for the last character pressed (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx for details).

You need code something like this:

```
double answer = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

This takes the entire input (which might be more than one character) and converts it to a double (Console.ReadLine returns a string) so you are comparing like with like.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Read();
```

returns an int value(The ASCII code) and you are storing this as answer which is of type double ! Use

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

instead ! Also you need to convert your answer to a double value to be able to compare your answer to the solution!